# Array list content isnt showing properly and skipping some data from start

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to create a list of students using array and display is inside div . I created a list using javascript code listed below , but the problem i am facing is that when the list gets bigger  i tried css property overflow auto to fix the overflow issue but its skips some of my data from start kindly someone help me out i am new to javascript

```js
const student_list = [
'moiz',
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie' 
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie',
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
,
'John'
, 'Adam'
, 'Walter'
, 'Jesse'
, 'Charlie'
]


let list = document.getElementById('list_of_students');
student_list.forEach((item) => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = item;
  list.appendChild(li);
})
```

```css
#studentsdata {
  /* color: white; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list_of_students ol {
  display: list-item;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#list_of_students li {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div id="studentsdata">
  <ol id="list_of_students"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? "when the list gets bigger" what happens?

Comment: There's no overflow in the code you posted. Also, it would be easier if you didn't make white-on-white text.

Comment: hi, actually when list get bigger the data display in html div overflow , to fix that i used css property overflow:auto but i ended up with  scroll bar and missing data from start like list containe 1 to 100 name of students and display form 35 to 100 like this it skips the data from 1 to 35

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE : **color:white** and **height** from css from #studentsdata

```js
const student_list = [
  'moiz', 'John', 'Adam', 'Walter', 'Jesse', 'Charlie','Walter', 'Jesse', 'Charlie'
]
let list = document.getElementById('list_of_students');
student_list.forEach((item) => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = item;
  list.appendChild(li);
})
```

```css
#studentsdata {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list_of_students
{
   max-height:200px;
   overflow: auto;
}
#list_of_students ol {
  display: list-item;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#list_of_students li {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div id="studentsdata">
  <ol id="list_of_students"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: hi , color white i  used because my main container have black background to make the text visible ,, secondly i want to display the data inside that div with a scroll bar

Comment: @AbdullahMOiz answer Updated

Answer (score 0):

try not to set width or height for elements exact size try in #list_of_students li ,auto-height and use camelCase for naming in JavaScript codes .

Comment: I removed hight and width and make height auto in #list_of_students li . But content is still showing from 50 . Not from 1 i want to show data from item 1 to nth size of array.

Comment: what about your parent element?#studentsdata ? overflow and scroll-bar  is necessary when you have a lot of elements in your page and you want to handle your contents

Comment: Yes . I want to keep the list with in div with a specific height . I have already fixed this .issue by inspecting i see i did my ol as flex box that creating all the mess when i removed display flex. everything is fine now. Thank you .